# Rails cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails without using dependent destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way I can bypass the foreign key constraint error without removing the foreign key? I do not want to do `dependent destroy`

I am trying to use `delayed_jobs` to delete massive amount of records from my db but I am getting a `cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails` because my `numbers` table has a foreign key `user_id`

this is my user model where I am delete a user and in the callback I am calling the method to delete all numbers associated with the user

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :numbers, inverse_of: :user
before_destroy :schedule_number_destroy


def schedule_number_destroy
 user_id = self.id
 User.delay(run_at: 40.minutes.from_now).destroy_numbers(user_id)
end

def self.destroy_numbers(user_id)
 loop do
  numbers = Number.where(user_id: user_id).limit(5000)
  break if numbers.count == 0
  numbers.destroy_all
  sleep(2)
 end
end
```

number model

```
class Number < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
# app/models/user.rb

has_many :numbers, dependent: :nullify
```

When you'll delete any user it will remove `user_id` from associated numbers.

Comment: I tried that, it does not work with `delayed_jobs`. to my understanding when using `dependent: :nullify` it dos not call any callbacks which means it never does delayed_jobs. It deletes all at once but with many records I do not want to overload my server